# Binding MonoTouch NSObject Categories

Tags: objective-c, ios5, binding, xamarin.ios

How can I bind this using `MonoTouch`??

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 60000
@interface NSObject (SubscriptingSupport)

- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;

@end
#endif
```

Tried this following [Documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Class_Extensions) but had no luck

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject)), Bind ("NSObject")]
public interface NSObject2 
{
    [Bind("objectAtIndexedSubscript:")]
    NSObject ObjectAtIndexedSubscript (uint idx);

    [Bind("setObject:atIndexedSubscript:")]
    void SetObjectAtIndexedSubscript (NSObject obj, uint idx);

    [Bind("setObject:forKeyedSubscript:")]
    void SetObjectForKeyedSubscript (NSObject obj, NSObject key);

    [Bind("objectForKeyedSubscript:")]
    NSObject ObjectForKeyedSubscript (NSObject key);
}
```

it gives tons of errors like

> Error CS0115: `DocParser.Dispose(bool)' is marked as an override but
>   no suitable method found to override (CS0115)

Thanks in advance

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding tool does not have support for generating stubs for extensions to core classes.

The good news is that fundamentally, the work is very simple: you must send a message to an object of instance NSObject.

This means that you can write the code by hand that does something like:

```
 void GetObjectAtIndex (NSObject target, int objectAt)
 {
     Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.objc_msgSend_int (target.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("objectAtIndexedSubscript:", objectAt));
 }
```

The above can be cumbersome to write by hand, so you can run the generator on a fictitious class and then copy/paste the results into your own class that takes a parameter "NSObject target" as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep the class name the same, as long as you have a different namespace besides `MonoTouch.Foundation`:

```
namespace WhateverNamespaceYouWantBesidesMonoTouch.Foundation
{
  [BaseType (typeof (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject))]
  public interface NSObject
  {
    [Export("objectAtIndexedSubscript:")]
    MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject ObjectAtIndexedSubscript (uint idx);

    [Export("setObject:atIndexedSubscript:")]
    void SetObjectAtIndexedSubscript (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject obj, uint idx);

    [Export("setObject:forKeyedSubscript:")]
    void SetObjectForKeyedSubscript (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject obj, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject key);

    [Export("objectForKeyedSubscript:")]
    MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject ObjectForKeyedSubscript (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject key);
  }
}
```

I'm also not sure what [Bind] does, you should use [Export] instead.

Comment: Hello jonathanpeppers as far as I understand Bind ("NSObject") Attaches all the interface code to NSObject class as seen here https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/foundation.cs#L3317 that is what I believe, I could be wrong, But I guess It is only if you build from source because on the resulting code .g.cs files it uses my own namespace and it is declared as `public partial class NSObject` I tried to use `MonoTouch.Foundation` instead my own namespace but it failed too since MonoTouch.dll NSObject its not partial

Comment: Also tried to extend the NSObject class by changing the resulting code  on NSObject.g.cs to be `Static` (Extension Methods) but it didn't work either. I'm trying your solution now will ping back with results

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either I get tons of errors like this -> `Error CS0115: DocParser.Dispose(bool) is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)`

Comment: Can you post a link to the library you are trying to bind?